# Why is Bitwise AND operator used for comparing singleton address and 0xfff... in GnosisSafeProxy.sol

Tags: gnosis-safe, proxy-contracts, safe-core

What is the purpose of using Bitwise AND operator to get singleton address in the fallback function of GnosisSafeProxy.sol? Each bit of `sload(0)` , singleton address and `0xffff...` are compared, although `sload(0)` would always return a value stored in storage slot 0 which should be singleton address.

```
 assembly {
    let _singleton := and(sload(0), 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
  ・・・
 }
```

ref:https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/ee92957307653ae6cf7312bbcb1a13c6884ea6ea/contracts/proxies/GnosisSafeProxy.sol#L29

Answer (score 5):

General objective of doing this and operation is to get extract the 20 bytes address with in a 32 bytes slot. There can be packed values with the address to clean up this is needed. The following example will give a good understanding.

```js
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

import "./Gnosis.sol";

contract childProxy is GnosisSafeProxy {
    bool A = true;

    constructor(address singleton) GnosisSafeProxy(singleton){

    }

    function getSlotValue(uint256 slot) external view returns(bytes32 ret){
        assembly {
            ret := sload(slot)
        }
    }

}
```

deploying this contract with the address`0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4` as the singleton address.

reading the slot 0 value

```js
> 0x0000000000000000000000015b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4
```

In the output additional **1** is available with the address. The Boolean value is also packed with the slot 0 as an address only needs 20 bytes. To extract the address needed, bitwise and operation is used here.

Input

```js
and(0x0000000000000000000000015b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4, 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff)
```

output

```js
> 0x0000000000000000000000005b38da6a701c568545dcfcb03fcb875f56beddc4
```

**EDIT**

This same scenario can happen when delegating, if the logic contract has a value which is possible to be packed in the same given slot 1, using the and operation to clean up ensures the cleaned address retrieval.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Interesting. Though, I wonder why you should be cautious about possible packed values in this case where the GnosisSafeProxy contract doesn't have any storage values declared before `singleton`. You know you wouldn't put anything that could cause trouble as a deployer, would you?